# java Unsupported Operation Exception

Tags: java, class, validation

I am trying to create three different classes for my code: `FutureValueApp`, `Validator`, and `FinancialCalculations`. I am following instructions, however, when I run the code, I keep getting the following error and and have no idea how to fix it.

```
==============================================================================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at FutureValueApp.getDoubleWithinRange(FutureValueApp.java:64)
    at FutureValueApp.main(FutureValueApp.java:17)

Java Result: 1

==================================================================================
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class FutureValueApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
        // get the input from the user
            System.out.println("DATA ENTRY");
            double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
            double interestRate = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter yearly interest rate: ", 0, 30);
            int years = getIntWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);

        // calculate the future value
            double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12/100;
            int months = years * 12;
            double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
                monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);

        // get the currency and percent formatters
            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
            percent.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);

        // format the result as a single string
            String results =
            "Monthly investment:\t"
            + currency.format(monthlyInvestment) + "\n"
            + "Yearly interest rate:\t"
            + percent.format(interestRate/100) + "\n"
            + "Number of years:\t"
            +  years + "\n"
            + "Future value:\t\t"
            + currency.format(futureValue) + "\n";

        // print the results
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("FORMATTED RESULTS");
            System.out.println(results);

        // see if the user wants to continue
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String enter_number_of_years_, int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String enter_monthly_investment_, int i, int i0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment, double monthlyInterestRate, int months) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Validator class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Validator 
{
    public static double getDouble(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        double d = 0.0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextDouble())
            {
                d = sc.nextDouble();
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid decimal value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return d;
    } 

    public static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
        double min, double max)
    {
        double d = 0.0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            d = getDouble(sc, prompt);
            if (d <= min)
                System.out.println(
                    "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            else if (d >= max)
                System.out.println(
                    "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            else
                isValid = true;
        }
        return d;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String prompt)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            if (sc.hasNextInt())
            {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                isValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Invalid integer value. Try again.");
            }
            sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String prompt,
        int min, int max)
    {
        int i = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        while (isValid == false)
        {
            i = getInt(sc, prompt);
            if (i <= min)
                System.out.println(
                    "Error! Number must be greater than " + min + ".");
            else if (i >= max)
                System.out.println(
                    "Error! Number must be less than " + max + ".");
            else
                isValid = true;
        }
        return i;
    }  
}
```

FinancialCalculations class

```
public class FinancialCalculations 
{

    public static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment,
        double monthlyInterestRate, int months)
    {
        double futureValue = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
        {
            futureValue =
            (futureValue + monthlyInvestment) *
            (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
        }
        return futureValue;
    }  
}
```

I know that the "Private UnsupportedOperationException" shouldn't be included in order to make the code work properly and that I need to make it public, but this is so confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing implementation of the method

```
private static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String enter_monthly_investment_, int i, int i0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Just implement it and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

You have **two** methods called `getDoubleWithinRange` (same is true of `getIntWithinRange` and `calculateFutureValue` as well). Your issue is that you're *calling the wrong ones*.

This line:

```
double monthlyInvestment = getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
```

Is calling the `static` `getDoubleWithinRange` method of the `FutureValueApp` class, which can only throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. It's doing this because you haven't qualified the method call with the owning class.

The method you want to call is the one in the `Validator` class, which you need to call like this:

```
double monthlyInvestment = Validator.getDoubleWithinRange(sc,
                "Enter monthly investment: ", 0, 1000);
```

Similarly, the line:

```
int years = getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);
```

Needs to be:

```
int years = Validator.getIntWithinRange(sc, "Enter number of years: ", 0, 100);
```

And:

```
double futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
                monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);
```

Needs to become:

```
double futureValue = FinancialCalculations.calculateFutureValue(
                monthlyInvestment, monthlyInterestRate, months);
```

Whenever you're dealing with `static` methods, it's good practice to *always* qualify the call with the owning class - had you done so in this instance you would have been able to spot the problem immediately.

It's also a good idea to delete the redundant methods from `FutureValueApp`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you have not implemented three methods, and they are throwing exceptions automatically.

```
private static int getIntWithinRange(Scanner sc, String enter_number_of_years_, int i, int i0) {
    return 0;
}

private static double getDoubleWithinRange(Scanner sc, String enter_monthly_investment_, int i, int i0) {
    return 0;
}

private static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyInvestment, double monthlyInterestRate, int months) {
    return 0;
}
```

In order to test your code, you can do what I have done above, just set a return value, and your console should print out:

> Welcome to the Future Value Calculator
>
> DATA ENTRY
>
> FORMATTED RESULTS Monthly investment: NOK 0.00 Yearly interest
>   rate: 0.0% Number of years:   0 Future value:     NOK 0.00
>
> Continue? (y/n):

Comment: No offense, but he has implemented them. Twice. The problem is, as JonK correctly pointed out, that the bad versions of the methods were used, they are throwing the Exceptions.

Comment: None taken, but these are the methods that he is calling, I was just referring to that. He has not implemented the same methods twice, but there are two classes with methods that share the same name, that is not the same as same methods. :-)